# Color overlay with ken burns effect slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a ken burns effect slideshow running with multiple pictures. I want to add an overlay on the mobile site of the slideshow, where the colours are switching between green red yellow and blue automatically. The overlay is not appearing and I can't figure out the problem. Any help is appreciated.

HTML:

```
 <div id="slideshow">
     <img src="images/Campus2.jpg" alt="school pic">
     <img src="images/bio_lab_optimised.jpg" alt="bio lab pic">
     <img src="images/Capture.jpg" alt="school pic">
     <img src="images/class_optimised.jpg" alt="class pic">
     <img src="images/LFPS_optimised.jpg" alt="school pic">
     <img src="images/phy_lab_optimmised.jpg" alt="physics lab">
     <img src="images/cs_lab.jpg" alt="class pic">
     <img src="images/x-optimised.jpg" alt="school pic">
     <img src="images/page-1-hero-image.jpg" alt="school's image">
     <img src="images/kindergarten2.jpg" alt="kindergarten">


</div>
```

CSS: (for overlay)

```
.overlay {
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display: block;
    z-index:3;
    animation: color-animation 80s linear alternate;
}

@keyframes color-animation {
    0% {
        background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
    }

    25% {
        background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
    }

    50% {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
    }

    100% {
        background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.5);
    }
}
```

CSS: (ken burns effect)

```
#slideshow{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

#slideshow img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    /* to make pic responsive */
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity, -webkit-transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 3s, 45s;
    -moz-transition-property: opacity, -moz-transform;
    -moz-transition-duration: 3s, 45s;
    -ms-transition-property: opacity, -ms-transform;
    -ms-transition-duration: 3s, 45s;
    -o-transition-property: opacity, -o-transform;
    -o-transition-duration: 3s, 4s;
    transition-property: opacity, transform;
    transition-duration:3s, 45s;
}

#slideshow img {
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -moz-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -ms-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -o-transform-origin: bottom left;
    transform-origin: bottom left;
}

#slideshow img:nth-child(2n+1) {
    -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
    -moz-transform-origin: top right;
    -ms-transform-origin: top right;
    -o-transform-origin: top right;
    transform-origin: top right;
}

#slideshow img:nth-child(3n+1) {
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
    -moz-transform-origin: top left;
    -ms-transform-origin: top left;
    -o-transform-origin: top left;
    transform-origin: top left;
}
#slideshow img:nth-child(4n+1) {
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom right;
    -moz-transform-origin: bottom right;
    -ms-transform-origin: bottom right;
    -o-transform-origin: bottom right;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
}

/**
 * Because of the stacking context, we need to make sure that the first image (in source) is not hidden by the last one.
 * The rule below moves all images past the second one down the stack.
 * This is because the second image needs to show on top of the first one when it transitions in.
 */

#slideshow .fx:first-child + img ~ img  {
    z-index:-1;
}

/**
 * Because images are styled with a different point of origin, the following rule will create different panning effects.
 */

#slideshow .fx {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
    -o-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Javascript:

```
 function slideEffect(){
            //apply fx class to first element
            document.getElementById('slideshow').getElementsByTagName('img')[0].className = "fx";
            //loop kenburns effect every 15 seconds
            window.setInterval(kenBurns, 15000);
            //gets all images under slideshow
            var images = document.getElementById('slideshow').getElementsByTagName('img'),
                    numberOfImages  = images.length,
                    i= 1;

            function kenBurns() {
                //applies class fx appropriately
                if(i==numberOfImages){ i = 0;}
                images[i].className = "fx";
                if(i===0){ images[numberOfImages-2].className = "";}
                if(i===1){ images[numberOfImages-1].className = "";}
                if(i>1){ images[i-2].className = "";}
                i++;
            }
        };

if (window.innerWidth < 480)
{
     $('#slideshow').addClass('.overlay');
}
slideEffect();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically just changing the style of `#slideshow`.

What you properly want instead, is to add a separate overlay on top of the slider. To do that I would highly recommend to use a pseudo-element.

I would also recommend to use media-queries instead of your JavaScript solution. It's a bit nicer.

**If you want to keep your way, change** `.overlay` **to this:**

```
.overlay:before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:3;
    animation: color-animation 80s linear alternate;
}
```

..or if you want to use media-queries instead, remove this:

```
if (window.innerWidth < 480)
{
     $('#slideshow').addClass('.overlay');
}
```

..and add this to the CSS instead:

```
@media screen and (max-width : 480px) {
    #slideshow:before {
        display: block;
        content: '';
        position: relative;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        z-index:3;
        animation: color-animation 80s linear alternate;
    }
}
```

It almost do the exact same thing. When the screen width is lower than 480px, a pseudo-element is added to `#slideshow`, which in fact is the overlay.